# Type erasure in generics confusion

Tags: java, generics, collections, overloading

I was reading concept of type erasure in generics. While executing the below piece of code I got confused.

```
public class CollectionsWild {
    void Test(Collection<?> t){
        System.out.println("Collection");
    }

    void Test(List<Integer> t){
        System.out.println("List");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollectionsWild o = new CollectionsWild();
        o.Test(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

}
```

As per the type erasure concept, "`List<Integer> t`" is converted to "List t" in bytecode. So why is my method test called which is having Collection as the parameter. It should have called the method with List as parameter

Comment: Thanks, but the link which you gave is not related to what I was asking..

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with erasure. Overload resolution is done at compile time. Only one overload matches `ArrayList<String>` and that is the one that is chosen. If there was more than one match, the most specific would have been selected.

In the case that of overloading with the same type erasure, the definition of the type does not compile before overload resolution is even considered.

Answer (score 2):

Method selection is a compile-time thing. Type erasure happens *afterward*. As you can see in [JLS§15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), generic type parameters *are* considered:

> Deciding whether a method is applicable will, in the case of generic methods (§8.4.4), require an analysis of the type arguments.